# Hide second-row transparent faces?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, transparency

I'm trying to display a geographically complex, semi-transparent (e.g. alpha = 0.5) object (terrain). When I render this object, the hidden front-faces of this object will also be drawn (like a hill that actually lies behind another one).

I would like to see other objects behind my "terrain" object, but don't want to see the hidden faces of my terrain (the second hill). So actually set the transparency for the "whole" object, not for single faces.

**Q:** How could I achieve to hide the "hidden" front-faces of a semi-transparent object?

I'm setting the transparency in the vertex shader by multiplying the color vector with the desired transparency:

```
fColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0);
fColor *= 0.5;
// fColor goes to fragment shader
```

`GL_DEPTH_TEST` is activated with `GL_LEQUAL` as depth function.

`GL_BLEND` is activated with `GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` as blending functions.

I tried to deactivate the depth buffer by `GLES20.glDepthMask(false);` before drawing, but this doesn't make any difference.

Probably I don't get the idea for the right depth buffer settings or the blending functions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I got it now:

Actually I can resign on blending at all. With the depth test switched on only the foreground fragments are visible (the front hill of my terrain). With the multiplication in the vertex shader the fragment shader will draw these visible fragments with desired transparency (the terrain as a whole becomes semi-transparent).

So, depth test on, blending off, color multiplication in vertex shader.